# Загрузить файл yii

Tags: yii

Как можно загрузить файл в yii без генерации формы средствами фраэмворка. 
В контролере есть массив $_FILES.

Answer (score 1):

http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/form.file.upload
http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/form.file.upload.fat.model
читайте документацию хорошо! В форумах примеров полно.

Comment: это не то, тут требуется в форме <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>

такое не катит.

Comment: Ну так обойдите требования, по ссылки выше - универсальное решение, на котором можно построить загрузку из любого жуквериплагина, например.

Comment: что то не получается, пишет постоянно что saveAs не определен 

             $ProfileModel->avatar=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
$ProfileModel->avatar->saveAs('test.jpg');